# Spring Integration HTTP Outbound Gateway Retry on Exception

Tags: spring-integration

I am new to Spring Integration. Below given is my code.

```
<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter
    id="testListenter" destination-name="testQueue"
    channel="setTestHeader" concurrent-consumers="2"
    max-concurrent-consumers="5" connection-factory="amqConnectionFactory" />

<http:outbound-gateway request-channel="httpChannel"
    url="http://APITesting/testHttp/v1.0" http-method="POST"
    header-mapper="headerMapper" reply-channel="response.header.enricher"
    error-handler="testErrorHandler"
    expected-response-type="com.test.domain.response.responseObject" message-converters="messageConverters" />

<util:list id="messageConverters">
    <bean id="formHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter"/>
    <bean id ="mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter"/>
</util:list>
```

I am not seeing any exceptions in my logs.

Now I am expecting the response to be a JSON. But If the response is not JSON and is of type raw, the outbound gateway is being fired atleast 7 times automatically.

Any help as why the API is being fired in case of scenarios like this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you don't have any `RequestHandlerRetryAdvice` there for that `<http:outbound-gateway>`, that " atleast 7 times automatically" is fully depends on the upstream caller. For example JMS Message Driver Channel Adapter makes a redelivery of the same message, if there is some exception is downstream.

The same we have with the AMQP.

So, "what is in your wallet?"

Please, share `DEBUG` logs for the `org.springframework.integration` category when you are observing the retry behavior.

Comment: Hi Artem, yes you are right, My upstream caller is JMS Message Driven Channel Adapter and I haven't configured an error channel. but My understanding was, the error handler that i have configured for the outbound gateway was supposed to catch the exception. Kindly correct me if I am wrong. <br>

Comment: You should move the code to your question via an `edit` function. And no, `error-channel` to prevent redelivery should be declared on the `JMS Message Driven Channel Adapter`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I added my code to the question.

Comment: M-m-m. I think response is fine. See `RestTemplate.handleResponse()`. That is the place where that your HTTP `ErrorHandler` is supposed to be called. But (!) you have a good response and it goes further by your reply process. That's why I ask you to move the flow error handling to the `erro-channel` subscriber from the JMS Message Driven Channel Adapter level already.